# Properly detecting numeric data in ajax xml response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I'm using jQuery to post ajax requests, and PHP to construct XML responses. Everything works fine, but I wonder about the method I've used for data typing, and whether there's a more standard way, or a more correct way. My XML generally looks like this, with some attributes representing text and other attributes representing numeric data:

```
<UnitConversions>
    <UnitConversion basicUnitName="mile" conversionFactor="5280" conversionUnit="foot"/>
    <UnitConversion basicUnitName="mile" conversionFactor="1760" conversionUnit="yard"/>
</UnitConversions>
```

I have a lot of different objects, not just this one type, so in my constructors, rather than initializing every property explicitly, I just copy the attributes over from the XML node:

```
var UnitConverter = function(inUnitConversionNode) {
    var that = this;
    $.each(inUnitConversionNode.attributes, function(i, attribute) {
        that[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
    });
};
```

I had trouble early on when I checked for numeric values, as in `if(someValueFromTheXML === 1)` -- this would always evaluate to `false` because the value from the XML was a string, "1". So I added nodes in key places in the XML to tell my client-side code what to interpret as numeric and what to leave as text:

```
<UnitConversions>
    <NumericFields>
        <NumericField fieldName="conversionFactor"/>
    </NumericFields>
    <UnitConversion basicUnitName="mile" conversionFactor="5280" conversionUnit="foot"/>
    <UnitConversion basicUnitName="mile" conversionFactor="1760" conversionUnit="yard"/>
</UnitConversions>
```

So now I pass the NumericFields node into the constructor so it will know which fields to store as actual numbers.

This all works great, but it seems like a bit of a naive solution, maybe even a hack. Seems like there would be something more sophisticated out there. It seems like this issue is related to XML schemas, but my googling seems to suggest that schemas are more about validation, rather than typing, and they seem to be geared toward server-side processing anyway.

What's the standard/correct way for js to know which fields in the XML are numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isNaN()` to detect whether the string is a number. For example `isNaN("5043")` returns false indicating that "5043" can be parsed as a number. Then, just use `parseInt()` to compare the value. For example:

```
if (parseInt(someValueFromTheXML, 10) === 1) {
 ...
}
```

Another way is to use loose comparison with the == operator so that "1" == 1 evaluates to true. However, it would be better practice to use the first suggestion instead. There is really no other way to go about this since XML/HTML attributes are always strings.

Comment: I'm relieved. I sort of expected a flood of answers along the lines that it's a dumb question with an easy, industry-standard answer. I like the `isNaN()` idea a lot. Thanks much.